# Django 1.10.2 error "NoReverseMatch at " ,"Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, django-1.10

I am new to python & Django. I am getting one error and have absolutely no idea how to solve it.
Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
#log/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.
# this login required decorator is to not allow to any
# view without authenticating
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def home(request):
     return render(request,"home.html")
```

The code in urls.py is,

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from log.forms import LoginForm
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 url(r'', include('log.urls')),
 url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login ,{'template_name':   'login.html','authentication_form': LoginForm}),
 url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
 ]
```

The code in login.html is,

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}

<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

<p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}

<p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

                        <p class="bs-component">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </p>
                        <p class="bs-component">
                            <center>
                                <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="login" />
                            </center>
                        </p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}


<script>
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
$("ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").css("display","none");
{% endif %}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Hope this much info will do....

Answer (score 2):

Add a `name` to the login *url pattern*:

```
kwargs = {'template_name': 'login.html','authentication_form': LoginForm}
...
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, kwargs=kwargs, name='login'),
#                                                  ^^^^
```

and then use that `name` in your template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```